# enhancing `[Authorize]` attribute in asp.net MVC web application with identity framework

Tags: asp.net, cookies, identity

Is there any simple way for enhancing `[Authorize]` attribute in asp.net MVC web application with identity framework ? the problem is when I use `[Authorize]` attribute for restrict anonymous access to ye controller or action if the user logged in in past and had the cookie now in spite of he was deleted from users table (i completely delete the database for make sure) he can access that controller. is it logical someone with that cookie always can have access to restricted areas?

Comment: I'm not really 100% sure what it is that you are asking, but have you tried inheriting from the attribute?

Comment: sorry for my bad English! no but I think there should be a simpler and more logical way because with this issue every on with that cookie can access the restricted area

Comment: Have you looked into Roles?

Comment: I think my major problem is I cant understand how framework can authorize someone without checking users database?